# create new columns and unselect existing columns without altering table schema

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

new to PL/SQL and wondering if I'd be able to create new columns, drop existing columns WITHOUT altering the table schema/source table, so that the source table remains untouched while the procedure returns a new result set that has new columns. for example,

```
id name type
1 foo  apple
2 bar  orange
```

Is it possible to write a stored procedure that unselects the column 'type' and creates new column 'value' that satisfies following condition:

```
if name = 'foo' then value = 5
elsif name = 'bar' then value = 7
```

so my result set would look like this:

```
id name value
1 foo  5
2 bar  7
```

Can this be done by purely using the pl/sql engine?

**Secondly**, would it be possible to create a variable that stores the output of a SQL that generates a alter table statement, and execute that variable so the alter table statement gets executed?

Comment: Procedures don't return result sets. Are you talking about pipelined functions?

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language and it is different to the SQL (query) language. Are you sure you want to do this using solely PL/SQL (its probably going to be impossible) or are you confusing the terminology and want it done in SQL (of the Oracle dialect)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you actually want a **view**, not any kind of PL/SQL code.

Table:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2  select 1 id, 'foo' name, 'apple' type from dual union all
  3  select 2, 'bar', 'orange' from dual;

Table created.
```

View:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2    select id,
  3           name,
  4           case when name = 'foo' then 5
  5                when name = 'bar' then 7
  6           end as value
  7  from test;

View created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID NAM      VALUE
---------- --- ----------
         1 foo          5
         2 bar          7

SQL>
```

---

If you really want PL/SQL, then using a function which returns ref cursor might be one option; you'd do that "logic" stuff in its `select` statement (just like in the view):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for
  7      select id,
  8           name,
  9           case when name = 'foo' then 5
 10                when name = 'bar' then 7
 11           end as value
 12      from test;
 13
 14    return rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID NAM      VALUE
---------- --- ----------
         1 foo          5
         2 bar          7


SQL>
```

---

As of your question:

> ... create new columns, drop existing columns WITHOUT altering the table schema/source table

Nope. That's done with `ALTER TABLE`.

---

Finally, as of your *second* question: yes, you can use a variable and *execute* it using dynamic SQL, i.e. `execute immediate`:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAM TYPE
---------- --- ------
         1 foo apple
         2 bar orange

SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    l_str := 'alter table test rename column type to value';
  5    execute immediate l_str;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAM VALUE         --> column name has changed
---------- --- ------
         1 foo apple
         2 bar orange

SQL>
```